# Localizing in the view not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am using Rails.  I type in the console the following commands:

> I18n.locale = 'is'
>   => :is
>   I18n.localize(Date.today)
>   => "21.08.2014"
>   In the console this is working correctly. The date format is dd.mm.yyyy

In the view I have

```
<%= date_field_tag(:dagsetning_from, Date.today) %>
```

This gives 08/21/2014 in the input box mm/dd/yyyy US formatted date.

If I change this to:

```
<%= date_field_tag(:dagsetning_from, I18n.localize(Date.today)) %>
```

No date appears in the form.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have looked at this some more.  
If I place in the view  
<%= Date.today %>  

Output: 2014-08-22 and if I put <%= I18n.l(Date.today) %>

Output: 22.08.2014  

So the i18n localisation is working correctly.  

date_field_tag shows the date as 08/22/2014  
Does anyone know how to get date_field_tag to display date as 22.08.2014 using I18n.l

Answer (score 0):

> **The I18n.locale defaults to I18n.default_locale which defaults to :en**
>
> Read more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-a-locale

If **:is** is your default app's locale, then in your `config/application.rb` **uncomment** the following line: `config.i18n.default_locale = :de` and change its value appropriately to **:is**.

Otherwise, you can set a locale:

- implicitly: `I18n.locale = :is`
- or explicitly: `I18n.l Date.today, locale: :is`

Comment: I had this in my application.rb  
config.i18n.default_locale = 'is'  
Changed it to  
config.i18n.default_locale = :is  
as you suggested.  
Still no date appears in the form but the console gives the right - format.  
Then I also tried to explicitly in the view as you also suggested  
locale: :is  
But no date appears in the form.  
I am wondering why this works correctly in the console but not in the view?

Comment: I have found out that the date picker form helper date_field_tag is provided by the browser. I am using the Chrome browser latest version. The date format should be displayed by the browser per set locale on the machine it is running on. However Chrome is not doing this correctly. I switched to Opera and then the date is displayed correctly as specified by the is locale on the machine.